# want a calculation result instead of <bound method ...Python 2.8

Tags: methods

I have tried finding this in the docs but don't quite get it. I am starting to work with Classes, When I try to get the result, I get  instead of the actual 'width' I maybe I need to **get** but not sure.. It sounds too complicated just to get a result. Can someone advise?

I have:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, pt_ll, pt_ur):
        self.ll = pt_ll        
        self.lr = Point(pt_ur.x, pt_ll.y)
        self.ur = pt_ur
        self.ul = Point(pt_ll.x, pt_ur.y)
    def width(self):
        """Returns the width-float of the Rectangle."""
        w = self.ur.x - self.ll.x
        return w
```

Then I call it:

```
r = Rectangle(Point(0,0), Point(10,10))
print r.ur.x
print r.ll.x
print r.width
```

and get this output:

```
10.0
0.0
<bound method Rectangle.width of <__main__.Rectangle object at 0x000000000B5CBC50>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print r.width
```

This returns the width method itself, this is what you see in the output.
You want to call that method so you need to instead do this:

```
print r.width()
```

This hints at an interesting thing about python, you can pass around functions just like you can with other variables.